# using date intervals in conditional in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to see if two dates are at least 1 hour apart. something like:

```
    if Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: jsqMessage.date, to: lastMessage.date) > 1 {
```

but binary operators cannot be used on operands of type DateComponents. Any idea how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `dateComponents` does not return a number but a new `DateComponents` object. You would have to append `.hour` to get the number of hours between the two dates. Since `.hour` would return a type of `Int?` you need to unwrap it.

So your code would be something like

```
if Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: jsqMessage.date, to: lastMessage.date).hour! >= 1 {
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: hey thanks. It didn't work at first but it was because I had the from/to reversed

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to handle those type of comparisons, you could write an extension either on `DateComponents` or on `Int`. Otherwise, you need to compare the component itself (`hour` in this case):

```
if let hours = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: jsqMessage.date, to: lastMessage.date).hour,
   hours > 1 {

  // Something
}

// OR

if Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: jsqMessage.date, to: lastMessage.date).hour! > 1 {

  // Something
}
```

Comment: In this case `hours` can't be `nil` so the optional binding is useless.

Comment: Technically not, I still prefer not to force unwrap.

Comment: There is more than black and white (I want to say that forced unwrapping is not evil per se); if you explicitly specify the`hour` component, it's 100% guaranteed and safe that `hour` has a value.

Comment: But the API still returns `Optional`. It just comes down to personal preference (readability and style). I prefer to use that pattern, if possible. Updated answer to provide both ways.

Comment: Apple changed the date components to optionals just for convenience reasons to be able to create `DateComponents(hour:0, minute:0)` by omitting all other (unused) components. Once again, an optional is not  necessarily unsafe, it depends on the context.